Is this dual switched receptacle circuit compliant with code?
I would like to know if the wiring diagram shown is code compliant and will work and not cause the GFCI's to behave incorrectly (false trips etc.). I think this would work, but can't seem to find anything similiar in my searches.
I have a 1-gang box indoor for switch and a 14/3 wire running outside to a 2-gang outdoor box on exterior of house. I was planning to use a dual switch connected as shown.
I would like independent control of receptalces to control plug in string lights and plug in landscape lighting transformer. I'd welcome any other options as well.
Since GFCI receptacles can't be split, I figured my options are:
a) Two independent GFCI receptacles each controlled by a switch
b) Use GFCI breaker and regular non-GFCI weather resistant receptacles. I'm not sure if these WR can be split either, so I might need 2 as well.
I am in NY USA for applicable code compliance.


Some GFCI's have an auto-test on power up, meaning you'll be pressing the Reset button every time you flip the switch. Putting the GFCI before the switch as DoxyLover suggests below will prevent this if you happen to have or ever replace with these auto-test GFCI's.

What you propose will work fine and is code compliant since your box is on the exterior of the house. If the box was away from your house, you wouldn’t be able to run Romex (NM-B) to the box because you can’t run it in a damp environment. Outdoor conduit is, by definition, a wet environment. You would need to replace that Romex with individual wet-rated wires in conduit.
However, I’d recommend against putting GFCI outlets outdoors. Even in a “weatherproof” box and cover, their lifespans will be limited. Your better choice would be a GFCI breaker or a dead-front GFCI before the switches. These will also allow you to use a single, split receptacle.

Many (not all) inspectors will allow Romex to the outdoors but only if it goes directly into the back of a box and not outdoors (even for an inch) before going into the box.

Regarding Romex in damp environment: This is why I described the outdoor box attached directly to house. It seems in this case you are allowed to use Romex (NM-B) as long as it terminates at that box and no where else. The inspector here passed that scenario previously in other applications (GFCI outdoor outlet, outdoor wall sconce)

Interesting note about GFCI outlets even if they are Weather Resistant. I'll take that into consideration. I already have a few Leviton WR GFCI outlets so we'll see how they hold up. I wasnt' sure if regular weather resistant (WR) receptacles can be split either. Some Levitons I had could not, if I recall correctly.

@QuestionsAnswers sorry, I missed that the box was on the exterior of the house.
